# Get first 100 values from MatOfKeyPoint in java opencv

Tags: java, opencv3.0, surf

I'm extracting **Surf_KeyPoints** from an image, *length* of **KeyPoints** is 130, now I want to get first **100** *KeyPoints* from it and store them back in that type of *variabe*/*object*...

```
int detectrType2 = FeatureDetector.SURF;
FeatureDetector surfDetector = FeatureDetector.create(detectrType2);
MatOfKeyPoint keypPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
surfDetector.detect(inputImg, keyPoints);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your data:

```
List input;
```

Then you can use the sublist method of Java to get only the first 100 elements

```
List croppedList = new ArrayList(input.subList(0, 100))
```

Of course at the type parameters to the list.

Comment: For this first I have to convert _keyPoints_ to _List_ then It can be done but I want them back in **keyPoints**. how can I convert **croppedList** to **keyPoints** ??

Comment: I dont know what this method returns: surfDetector.detect(); But i guess it is returning a List of Objects. I can not tell. But i can tell how to get only the first 100 elements, instead of the 130. Please look at the return type of the detect method.

Comment: return type is void and it has 2 arguments. First  _Mat_ and second _MatOfKeyPoint_ . Detects _KeyPoints_ from _image_ and _stores_ them in **MatOfKeyPoint_keyPoints**

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this :

`List<KeyPoint> first_100 = new ArrayList(keypPoints.toList().subList(0,100));`

Probably put this in a condition with respect to the size of `keypPoints`.